# Django Get image from s3 bucket if image source is stored in a database

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-media, django-uploads

I have a model where users upload pictures to an s3 bucket.

```
class Curso(models.Model):
    titulo = models.TextField()
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/cursos') #this goes to mybucket/media/cursos
    alt = models.TextField()
    ...
```

It uploads fine to the s3 bucket but the source to the images gets stored in the database like

```
"media/cursos/theimage.jpg"
```

And I would like to display the images from the objects in a template like this

```
 <img class='curso__tarjeta--imagen' loading="lazy" src="{{curso.foto}}" alt={{curso.alt}}">
```

But **it doesn't work because the path is not the whole path my s3 bucket**

My static tag is pointing to my s3 bucket. My question is: is there a way to do something like this ->

```
{% load static %}
<img class='curso__tarjeta--imagen' loading="lazy" src="{%static%}{{curso.foto}}" alt={{curso.alt}}">
```

I'm trying like that but it doesn't work!
What should I do?
Help! And thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to another stackoverflow answer I finally got it

```
<img class='curso__tarjeta--imagen' loading="lazy" src={{curso.foto.url}} alt="{{curso.alt}}">
```

And added this to settings.py

```
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
```